# Object doesn't support property or method 'on'

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, object, methods, dropzone.js

I'm hitting this Error on IE8 & 9. Haven't tested any higher yet but it's also coming form a plugin I'm using called '[Dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)' .

After including dropzone, in my onReady function I have:

```
if (typeof(Dropzone) != 'undefined') {
    var dz = new Dropzone('#dropzone', {options: here});
    dz.on('drop', ondropfunctionhere);
}
```

The options object has a whole heap more settings but I've left them out as I don't think they're what's causing the issue.

If have checked:

```
if (typeof(dz.on) == 'undefined') {
     dz.on = function (a, b) {
        return this._callbacks = this._callbacks || {}, (this._callbacks[a] = this._callbacks[a] || []).push(b), this
    }
}
```

I stole this function from my chrome debug when I output dz.on, but this still doesn't actually fire any of the callbacks. Are callbacks not defined in < IE 9 dropzone.js?

Comment: Did you look at the `dz` object in the debugger and see what it is and what methods it has?

Comment: Seeing as it works fine in Chrome I would assume that the method should still be there in IE, there's nothing I've read in the docs that state otherwise, that being said that doesn't mean it can't be true

Comment: @jfriend00 I have run `dz.hasOwnProperty('on')` and it returned false, I've also checked `typeof(dz.on)` and it return undefined.

Comment: This is a case where you don't want to use `hasOwnProperty()` because you want to see things on the prototype too.  You'd want to test `if (dz.on)` or `console.log(typeof dz.on)`.  The reason I asked about looking at `dz` in the debugger is that might give you some idea what's going on.  Also, what is the exact error you see in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [dropzone docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#browser-support), IE8 and IE9 are not supported:

> Browser Support
>
> Chrome 7+
>
> Firefox 4+
>
> IE 10+
>
> Opera 12+
>
> (Version 12 for MacOS is disabled because their API is buggy)
>
> Safari 6+

Comment: It does say after that though, that older browsers still get the fallback form just not the drag and drop features?

Comment: @ShannonHochkins - and you're trying to set up a drop zone right?  Are you surprised the dropzone doesn't work?

Comment: Dropzone does a hell of a lot more than just drag and drop though, i wanted to still utilize the callbacks for upload progress, onadding, on success. What's the point of them implementing a fallback form for ie9 if you have to completely write your own callbacks & functions as well?

Comment: @ShannonHochkins - Probably best to take that type of question to the dropzone people directly.  I'm just trying to help you troubleshoot.